# "Sarah has climbed the Matterhorn, sailed around the world"

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

> Sarah **has climbed** the Matterhorn, **sailed** around the world, and **has gone** on safari in Kenya. She is such an adventurous person.

Why is "sailed" in the *Simple Past* while the other verbs are in the *Simple Perfect*? (It is an example from a website on grammar.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tense is still *Present Perfect*, "*sailed*" is both the past simple form and the past participle of "*sail*". The subject (Sarah) and the auxiliary verb (has) are the same so they have been omitted. You can also say: "*Sarah has climbed the Matterhorn, she has sailed around the world, and she has gone on safari in Kenya*." but that is a bit clumsy.

Comment: Yes. The error (a small one) is repeating *has* in the third verb after omitting it in the second one, which muddies the ellipsis.

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't really see it as an "error" at all. There's nothing obviously wrong to my ear in something like *"I've been there, seen it, done it, and **have got** the t-shirt"* (which arguably allows you to put a little more emphasis on the final component). If in OP's example the final verb had been **safaried** instead of **gone on safari** extending the ellipsis would seem more natural, but because what we've actually got is a phrasal (as opposed to single-word) verb, it seems perfectly okay to me to treat that as a "breakpoint", and discontinue the ellipsis.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As I said, it's a small error; and it would indeed be justified if it marked the final term as semantically distinct for some reason. I'd be happy with *has A, B, C **—and has even D.*** I'm also happy with your first example, but that's only because in **my** dialect *have got* is a different construction: not a present perfect, as  *have gotten* would be! :)

Comment: @StoneyB: That's exactly my point - I *do* see the final term as (syntactically, not semantically) distinct. And I don't recognise any grammatical rule saying ellipsis must be continued as long as possible once it's started, so OP's example is at the very least "acceptable". And I wouldn't argue with a competent writer if they told me they'd chosen to use that form because they actually thought it was *better*.

Comment: @Stoney: I wonder if the writer would have been less inclined to use a second _has_ if the third verb ended with _-ed_, as in: _Sarah has climbed the Matterhorn, sailed around the world, and traveled on safari in Kenya._ Maybe – although this is just a theory – with the irregularly conjugated _gone_, the writer felt an extra _has_ would read better. I'd consider it neither correct nor incorrect, but optional.

Comment: @FumbleFingers see next

Comment: @J.R. and FumbleFingers You may both be right, and I certainly wouldn't take points off for the extra *has*. But it confused at least one person, *viz* OP :)

Comment: @StoneyB, J.R.: Let's not forget that the person who was confused isn't a native speaker, and thus arguably can't be considered part of the target readership. I didn't flag it up separately from my "phrasal verb" distinction, but I absolutely agree J.R.'s point that the fact of it not being an *-ed* verb form also creates a "disjunct" that [further] promotes the possibility of / justification for discontinuing the ellipsis.